# Is NVM working on latest Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL)?

Tags: nvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm able to install NVM via script and able to execute something like `nvm use v6.3.1`

However everytime I try to install stuff from my package.json i get permission denied errors as described here
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/14

I tried looking online but no clear answers. Is nvm working on the latest WSL?

Answer (score 0):

Is npm working ok for you?

Not sure if you error is related, but I found I had to either:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

or

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

in order to get Node to work properly.

Comment: hi, I think this is a known issue with node and ubuntu. There is an existing linux package called node that conflicts with javascript node. As a result you need to do a symlink as you describe.
my issue is sperate in that node install and paths are managed by NVM allowing me to use different node versions as needed.
The issues with npm outlined here are supposedly fixed in latest version of wsl